# How to specify concrete collection type in stream.collect(Collectors)

Tags: java-8, java-stream

How we can create some Concrete collection type from Stream.collect() method

e.g  for below example, I want to Created LinkedList instead of generic List.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10,20,30,40);
        List<Integer> collect3 = list.stream().filter(i ->i%2==0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I specify, I need to create `LinkedList`

Comment: You got an answer to your question, so you know now how to specify a concrete collection type, however, why do you want a `LinkedList `? There is almost no practical reason to want it. See also [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488)…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a constructor reference, LinkedList::new, and the Collectors.toCollection method.

```
list.stream().filter(i ->i%2==0).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
```